# How to take the max value of each category in 1 column across multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I am using Python 3.4 on Jupyternotebook.

I am looking to select the max of each product type from the below table. I've found the groupby code as written below but I am struggling to figure out how to do the search so that it takes into account the max for all box (box_1 and box_2), etc etc.

Perhaps best described as some sort of fuzzy matching?

Ideally my output should give me the max in each category:
box_2    18
bottles_3 31
.
.
.

How should I do this?

```
data = {'Product':['Box_1','Bottles_1','Pen_1','Markers_1','Bottles_2','Pen_2','Markers_2','Bottles_3','Box_2','Markers_2','Markers_3','Pen_3'], 
        'Sales':[14,24,31,12,13,7,9,31,18,16,18,14]}
 
df1=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Product','Sales']) 
df1

df1.groupby(['Product'])['Sales'].max()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you first have to look at the category and then retrieve both the name of the product and the maximum value. Here is how to do that:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Product','Sales']) 

df1['Category'] = df1.Product.str.split('_').str.get(0)

df1["rank"] = df1.groupby("Category")["Sales"].rank("dense", ascending=False)

df1[df1["rank"]==1.0][['Product','Sales']]
```

The rank function will rank the products within the categories according to their Sales value. Then, you need to filter out any category that ranks lower. That will give you the desired dataframe:

```
    Product     Sales
2   Pen_1       31
7   Bottles_3   31
8   Box_2       18
10  Markers_3   18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split values by `_`, select first values by indexing `str[0]` and pass to `groupby` and [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for `Product` by maximal `Sales`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Product')
df2 = (df1.groupby(df1.index.str.split('_').str[0])['Sales']
          .agg([('Product','idxmax'), ('Sales','max')])
          .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df2)
     Product  Sales
0  Bottles_3     31
1      Box_2     18
2  Markers_3     18
3      Pen_1     31
```

Comment: Thanks! It gives me the category only though, not the full product name. what would you suggest to return also the "_1" , "_2" where relevant

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
df1['Type'] = df1.Product.str.split('_').str.get(0)
df1.groupby(['Type'])['Sales'].max()

## -- End pasted text --
Out[1]: 
Type
Bottles    31
Box        18
Markers    18
Pen        31
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```